# MySQL insert big data in 5 sec

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, express, bigdata

Tech stack: express + typeorm + mysql

I'm looking for solution for this task:
I have csv file (100000+ rows), every row contain some data like: `reviewer, review, email, rating, employee, employee_position, employee_unique_id, company, company_description`
I need to save all this data into 5 different tables in the fastest way

```js
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string

  @Column()
  email: string

  @OneToMany(() => ReviewEntity, review => review.fromUser)
  reviews: ReviewEntity[]
}
```

```js
@Entity('review')
export class ReviewEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column('longtext')
  text: string

  @Column()
  rating: number

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user.reviews)
  fromUser: UserEntity

  @ManyToOne(() => EmployeeEntity, employee => employee.reviews)
  forEmployee: EmployeeEntity
}
```

```js
@Entity('employee')
export class EmployeeEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string

  @Column()
  name: string

  @ManyToOne(() => EmployeePositionEntity, position => position.employees)
  position: EmployeePositionEntity

  @ManyToOne(() => CompanyEntity, company => company.employees)
  company: CompanyEntity

  @OneToMany(() => ReviewEntity, review => review.forEmployee)
  reviews: ReviewEntity[]
}
```

```js
@Entity('employee_position')
export class EmployeePositionEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string

  @OneToMany(() => EmployeeEntity, employee => employee.position)
  employees: EmployeeEntity[]
}
```

```js
@Entity('company')
export class CompanyEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string

  @Column('longtext')
  description: string

  @OneToMany(() => EmployeeEntity, employee => employee.company)
  employees: EmployeeEntity[]
}
```

I tried to parse data into 5 arrays and save them in parallel with batch by 100 items, but it's takes too long

Comment: You can't beat [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) for bulk loading performance in MySQL. Even if you have to rewrite your csv file into five new csv files first. You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Answer (score 0):

**Fast LOAD**

1. `LOAD DATA INFILE` -- Bring all the data into a single table (`raw`) with all the columns.
2. `CREATE TABLE table1 SELECT ... FROM raw`;
3. Ditto for each other table.
4. `DROP TABLE raw`

That is, since the layout of the incoming data is not what you need, plan on using it only as a staging area for the other tables.

If part of the task is to "normalize" the data, it gets a little tricky to get the autoincrement ids in a timely manner.  That *may* necessitate this efficient way to do it (once per id):  [*Normalization*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) .

That might involve 5+1 full table scans.  But, by doing each entire task in a single query, it will be 10 times as fast as doing things one row at a time.

Also, I recommend coding it directly in MySQL queries instead of using a framework that might generate less-efficient SQL.

**Replacing?**  If the task is to *replace* all the data (and the data stays readonly), it is better to use these 3 steps:

1. `CREATE TABLEs` with temp names
2. Load the data into them (as discussed above)
3. Switch the new data in (almost instantly -- much less than 5 sec).

   ```
    RENAME TABLE main1 TO old1,
                 new1 TO main1,
                 main2 TO old2,
                 new2 TO main2
                 ...;
    DROP TABLE old1, old2, ...;
   ```

That limits the *downtime* to less than a second.

(I have discussed a way that works well for MySQL; I don't know about all the other tags you listed.)